# How to set MIME type to a buffer or url of image in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mime

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{

let searchTerm = req.body.search;
const kwords = new keywords({
    keyword: searchTerm
});
keywords.findOne({keyword: searchTerm}, function(err, key){
    if(err) throw err;
    else if(!key){
        kwords.save();
    }
});


google.list({
    keyword: searchTerm,
    num: 15,
    detail: false,
    nightmare: {
        show: false
    }
})
.then(function(images){

    images.forEach(function(image, index){

        let url = image.url;


        //compression
        Jimp.read(url,  function(err, img){ 

            if(err) throw err;
        if(img){  
            img.resize(256, 256)
              .quality(60)
              .greyscale()
              .write("public/images/"+searchTerm+index+".jpg");
             }
        });
    });
    res.redirect('/list');

}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('err', err);
});
```

});

I am using image-scraper and jimp library.
Inside Jimp.read() when an url doesn't have mime type , img becomes null,
so instead of fetching 15 images I get 13,14 most of the time. Somebody please help me to fix this issue so that i can get all 15images.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I'm looking for this too

Answer (score 0):

you should use promise methods instead of callback

```js
google.list({
    keyword: searchTerm,
    num: 15,
    detail: false,
    nightmare: {
        show: false
    }
})
.then(function(images){
    images.forEach(function(image, index){
        let url = image.url;
        //compression
        Jimp.read(url)
        .then(function(img) {
            if(img){  
              img.resize(256, 256)
               .quality(60)
               .greyscale()
               .write("public/images/"+searchTerm+index+".jpg");
            }
        }).catch(console.error)
    });
    res.redirect('/list');

})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log('err', err);
});
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? What is the problem and how did you fix it?